# Record does not insert in database

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, controller

I want to make a function for when a member gets premium then this function should be called. This is is the code that I have tried:

```php
public function updatePremium()
{             
    $comission = ChargeCommision::first();
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());              

    $ref_id = $user->referrer_id;
    $ref_user = User::find($ref_id);
    $new = $ref_user['earning']  = $ref_user['earning'] + $comission->update_commision_sponsor;
    $ref_user->save();        

    $new_balance = $user['balance'] =  $user['balance'] - $comission['update_charge'];
    $user['paid_status'] = 1;
    $user->save();

    Transaction::create([
        'user_id' => $ref_user->id,
        'trans_id' => rand(),
        'time' => Carbon::now(),
        'description' => 'REFERRAL COMMISSION'. '#ID'.'-'.'REF'.rand(),
        'amount' => $comission->update_commision_sponsor,
        'new_balance' => $new,
        //  need help here: I want to save a new column's value by the name of (new_earning)' => $new_earning,
        'type' => 1,
        'charge' => 0,
    ]);

    Income::create([
        'user_id' => $ref_user->id,
        'amount' => $comission->update_commision_sponsor,
        'description' => 'Deposit Commision From'.' '. $user->username,
        'type' => 'R'
    ]);        

    // Taka to sponsor
    updatePaid($user->id);
    // UPDATE BV
    updateDepositBV($user->id,'1');

    Transaction::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'trans_id' => rand(),
        'time' => Carbon::now(),
        'description' => 'UPGRADE TO PREMIUM'. '#ID'.'-'.'UPDATE'.rand(),
        'amount' => '-'.$comission['update_charge'],
        'new_balance' => $new_balance,
        //need help here: I want to save a new column's value by the name of (new_earning)' => $new_earning,
        'type' => 2,
        'charge' => 0,
    ]);

    return redirect()->back()->with('message','Congratulations, You are successfully upgrade your account' );
}
```

And I want some changes in it. Like I have added a new column in Transaction table and in Users table with the name of 'earning' and 'new_earning'and now I want to save the values in those two columns too as the other columns values get saved. But I am getting some errors.

The earning column of User table is getting saved the values but the new_earning column of Transaction table is not saving the values and giving me an error when user try to upgrade their account.

I have tried so many alternatives to get to know the error. When I remove the column new_earning (that I was added in the table while altering) from the Transaction table, the function works fine and the user gets no error. when I add that column again OR add any new column in the table of Transaction, user gets error while upgrading the account.

I can't understand that what is the error here. While storing the transactions in the Transaction table is most important.

Sorry for the very long text but I want to discuss completely so you can understand that what exactly I want to say. Thank you.

Comment: *"But I am getting some errors"*, *"giving me an error"*  - You keep saying "errors" and "the error", but you never actually said what these errors are. Edit your question and add the specific error messages and the actual code that generates them.

Comment: error means the page dose not open after clicking upgrade button, it says whoops something gone wrong on the whole page.

Comment: Right, and that error is logged somewhere. Check `storage/logs/laravel.log`; you'll see the errors there. Or, enable debug via `.env` settings `APP_DEBUG=true`

Comment: Alright I got the error log after enabling the APP_DEBUG. and the error is "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'new_earning' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `transactions` (`user_id`, `trans_id`, `time`, `description`, `amount`, `new_earning`, `type`, `charge`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 1942455888, 2019-09-23 18:32:45, REFERRAL COMMISSION#ID-REF144312709, 5, 225, 1, 0, 2019-09-23 18:32:45, 2019-09-23 18:32:45))
"   while the column 'new_earning' is exist in the transaction table

Comment: "*while the column 'new_earning' is exist in the transaction table*" - This error is very clearly saying that it does not... Have you updated your database? Are you using migrations? Run a `describe transactions;` (or equivalent for your DB system) and add the output of that to your question.

Comment: Got it. I have altered my table so I will have to run php artisan migrate to "push" the changes to database. But I don't have terminal in my hosting's cpanel. is there any way to do that?

Comment: That's correct; if you edit a migration, until you re-run `php artisan migrate`, the database hasn't actually changed yet. As far as terminal access, I'm not sure; you'll have to work that out with your hosting provider. It's definitely required for a number of Laravel functions though.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to install laravel on windows and then do further process?

Comment: Yeah, Laravel is compatible with any OS as long as you have the right stack setup (Windows/Linux/Mac, apache/nginx/etc, PHP and MySQL/MariaDB/SqlServer/etc).

Comment: Thank you man :)